MS EXCEL - Identify and Append Duplicate Values in Range/List with Unique Identifier
With the use of a MS Excel formula (Not VBA, etc.), I have a list of values in Column A, which also contains duplicates.  I would like a formula in the adjacent column, to identify, match and return both unique and duplicate values, whereas, if duplicate values are found in Column A, append with a unique sequential numerical value at the end of each unique duplicate match.  See below with desired output results in Column B.
Column A  |  Column B
Pears  |  Pears1
Apples  |  Apples1
Oranges  |  Oranges1
Pears  |  Pears2
Apples  |  Apples2
Watermelon  |  Watermelon1
Watermelon  |  Watermelon2
Bananas  |  Bananas1
Kiwi  |  Kiwi1
Pears  |  Pears3

You could use:
=A2&COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)


Thank you so much Rory for you quick and also perfect solution to my question, your formula works perfectly!!! Thanks again...
